# C# chart X Axis shorten the displayed Value

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, datagridview, linechart

is there a way to shorten the displayed value thats on the X axis. Right know its displaying year, month, day, hour, minutes, secounds, milisecounds and Timezone. Is it possilbe only to display hh:mm:ss

Current display in the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye1Xg.png)

I tried to change the Label format as well as the Value Type but it didnt change anything

```
chart1.Series["Regelungsdaten"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
                
                objChart.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss";
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911908/custom-label-on-x-axis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [custom label on x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911908/custom-label-on-x-axis)